# How can I extract data as object not array from MongoDB using Node.js/Express?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express

I'm learning MongoDB and Node.js. While I'm trying to making small database, I encountered a problem. The result of data is shown as array, not object.

What I want to do : show the result of data as object.

Data: `[{"_id":"59e06e1dbbeee5a09e8fb46b","id":"123","name":"Dog chew toy","price":10.99},{"_id":"59e06e1dbbeee5a09e8fb46c","id":"456","name":"Dog pillow","price":25.99}]`

When I type `localhost:3000/findToy?id=123`, the following data is shown.

`[{"_id":"59e06e1dbbeee5a09e8fb46b","id":"123","name":"Dog chew toy","price":10.99}]`

The data is array. But I want to show it as object like the below.

`{"_id":"59e06e1dbbeee5a09e8fb46b","id":"123","name":"Dog chew toy","price":10.99}`

How can I accomplish this?

index.js

```
var express = require('express');
var app = express();

app.set('view engine', 'ejs');

var bodyParser = require('body-parser');
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true}));
app.use(bodyParser.json());

var Animal = require('./Animal.js');
var Toy = require('./Toy.js');

var router = express.Router();

app.get('/findToy?:id', (req, res) => {

   var query = {};
   if(req.query.id) {
   query.id = {$regex: req.query.id };
   }
   if(Object.keys(query).length == 0){
   res.json({});
   }

 Toy.find(req.query.id,(err, toys) => {
      if(err) {
          res.type('html').status(500);
          res.send('Error:' + err);
      }
      else {
           res.json(toys);
          console.log(toys)
      }
    })
 }); 

app.listen(3000, () => {
console.log('Listening on port 3000');
});

module.exports = app;
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the findOne method instead of find()
[findOne documentation](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/db.collection.findOne/)